# Which statement will establish the database connection in Hibernate?

Tags: database, hibernate, session, connection

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
session.beginTransaction();
```

In the above code, which line will establish the database connection? Is each session a new Connection to the database in Hibernate?